# Prefix urls in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want all my pages in my 2.3 Rails application to have the url prefixed with:

```
www.example.com/app/
```

and I did this writing in `routes.rb` the following lines:

```
# I named the first part of the url ':appl'
map.root :appl => "app", :controller => "home"

# Default routes
map.connect ':appl/:controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':appl/:controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

It all works fine, with the exception of `map.resources`, where I have

```
map.resources :pages
```

and now wherever I have `edit_page_path` or `page`, the generated url's are not correct, because `app` is not inserted at the beginning. I've tried with `namespace` and `scope`, like I've seen [here in chapter 2.6](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but with no success.

How should I do this? Is the `:appl` in routes  a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I wrote in `routes.rb`:

```
map.resources :pages,   :as => 'app/pages'
```

Now, `edit_page_path` and others return the right path, prefixed with `'app'`

Answer (score 6):

If you are deploying on Passenger, you just need to set (in your webserver config):

`RailsBaseURI /app`

And then in your app's config:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/app'
```

You shouldn't need to worry about any sub-uri stuff beyond that. It should Just Work. See the [Passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) for more details.

For mongrel, you can use the --prefix option

```
script/server mongrel -P /app
```

Comment: What's your deployment stack? There may be a solution available there.